# How do I access the cannon outside the castle?

Tags: super-mario-64

There is a cannon just outside of the castle in Super Mario 64 but it's locked! The cannon is near the water on the beach.

Can I get access to the cannon? If so, how?

[image: Cannon with castle in background]

[image: Metal grate blocking cannon]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe you're talking about the cannon outside the castle in [Super Mario 64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super_Mario_64) - this cannon will launch you up to a secret area, but only if you've got all 120 stars.

For getting all the stars and accessing this secret cannon:

> Yoshi is up on top of the castle, and if you get up there, he'll hook you up with many extra lives :)

Answer (score 0):

There is another way to enter the cannon which involves a glitch, so if you haven't gotten all 120 stars you can still get in. There is a tree near where the cannon is which happens to be slightly buried under the terrain. What you need to do is to jump dive and catch the tree at the base such that half of mario's body clips under the terrain. Then just drop down from the tree, the water layer for the lake extends far from the basin so you won't fall out of the map. All you have to do now is swim to the cannon and you should be able to enter it.

Answer (score -3):

Carry out a triple jump, with the third jump taking place near the green wall to the right of the castle. Hang onto the roof and climb up to get to Yoshi.

Comment: This question is about how to unlock the cannon, not about how to get to the roof without it.

Comment: It's a good trick WITHOUT the cannon, but this person was asking how to use the cannon period! Perhaps you could present this in your own Q&A post?